# bigquery loading a csv(, field seperated) file having data between quotes and got one column as commas in between data

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, loading

i have a csv file like:

```
"id","name","address"

"10","aparna","hyderabad,hitech-city"

"11","mounika","hyderabad,kukatpally"

"12","raji","hyderabad,madhapur"
```

if I use `--autodetect` it is working, but if I use with schema it is giving me an error.

I want to load this file to a table in a big query like this

```
id    name      address

10    aparna    hyderabad,hitech-city

11    mounika   hyderabad,kukatpally

12    raji      hyderabad,madhapur
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f97J3.jpg)

for that, I used `bq load project:dataset.table gs://filepath schemafile` this is giving me an error like

```
.csv: Error
while reading data, error message: Too many values in row starting
at position: 0. Found 35 column(s) while expected 33.
- You are loading data without specifying data format, data will be
treated as CSV format by default. If this is not what you mean,
please specify data format by --source_format.
```

can anyone help me out in this

thanks in advance

Comment: if you open a sample of  your data  in excel, do you get an extra column? the address column with commas also is causing an error for csv.